# How to make the grid infinite in User Ortho Views?

Tags: 3d-view

If you go to the Top Ortho View and try to roll it from there (Numpad 4 or 6) to reach 90 degrees, the grid sort of becomes no longer infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's an option to do this specifically for orthographic mode, however if you go to the property panel (press N to make visible), under "display" you can set the number of lines to show on the grid. By setting it to its max value of 1024, this will achieve a similar effect to what you are looking for.[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a nice workaround. Interestingly, when I started rolling one of the side views by 90 degrees, the grid just disappeared. Maybe you can also suggest something for this issue?